# When changing to a branch in git, changes are detected - count is different every time

Tags: windows, git, azure-devops

I have a git repository with wired behavior: If I change to a branch of the repo, changes are detected. A diff shows no visible changes, so I think there's a problem with invisible characters?

After changing to main (force checkout) and back again, changes are still there, but their count is different.

Please see this redacted console log. I first switched branches several times and afterward I diffed a small file to get an idea what's wrong.

```
> git clone https://redacted Project
Cloning into 'Project'...
remote: Azure Repos
remote: Found 57799 objects to send. (385 ms)
Receiving objects: 100% (57799/57799), 779.81 MiB | 54.44 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (47237/47237), done.
Updating files: 100% (2975/2975), done.
> cd .\Project\
[main ≡]> git checkout Prod
Updating files: 100% (1597/1597), done.
Switched to a new branch 'Prod'
branch 'Prod' set up to track 'origin/Prod'.
[Prod ≡ +0 ~974 -0 !]> git checkout main -f
Updating files: 100% (1597/1597), done.
Switched to branch 'main'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
[main ≡]> git checkout Prod
Updating files: 100% (1597/1597), done.
Switched to branch 'Prod'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/Prod'.
[Prod ≡ +0 ~336 -0 !]> git checkout main -f
Updating files: 100% (1597/1597), done.
Switched to branch 'main'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
[main ≡]> git checkout Prod
Updating files: 100% (1597/1597), done.
Switched to branch 'Prod'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/Prod'.
[Prod ≡ +0 ~223 -0 !]> git checkout main -f
Updating files: 100% (1597/1597), done.
Switched to branch 'main'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
[main ≡]> git checkout Prod
Updating files: 100% (1597/1597), done.
Switched to branch 'Prod'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/Prod'.
[Prod ≡ +0 ~90 -0 !]> git checkout main -f
Updating files: 100% (1597/1597), done.
Switched to branch 'main'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
[main ≡]> git checkout Prod
Updating files: 100% (1597/1597), done.
Switched to branch 'Prod'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/Prod'.
[Prod ≡ +0 ~959 -0 !]> git version
git version 2.42.0.windows.1
[Prod ≡ +0 ~959 -0 !]> git diff <redacted>\ILandDao.cs
diff --git a/<redacted>/ILandDao.cs b/<redacted>/ILandDao.cs
index e9e70eb3..3e403dd3 100644
--- a/<redacted>/ILandDao.cs
+++ b/<redacted>/ILandDao.cs
@@ -1,23 +1,23 @@
-using System.Collections.Generic;
-using Project.Entity.Entities;
-
-namespace Project.Entity.Daos.Interfaces
-{
-    public interface ILandDao
-    {
-        #region methods
-
-        #region public methods
-
-        void Delete(LandEntity entity);
-        LandEntity GetById(int id);
-
-        IList<LandEntity> GetList();
-
-        int Save(LandEntity entity);
-
-        #endregion
-
-        #endregion
-    }
+using System.Collections.Generic;
+using Project.Entity.Entities;
+
+namespace Project.Entity.Daos.Interfaces
+{
+    public interface ILandDao
+    {
+        #region methods
+
+        #region public methods
+
+        void Delete(LandEntity entity);
+        LandEntity GetById(int id);
+
+        IList<LandEntity> GetList();
+
+        int Save(LandEntity entity);
+
+        #endregion
+
+        #endregion
+    }
 }
\ No newline at end of file
> git config -l
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
http.sslbackend=openssl
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
credential.helper=manager
core.editor="C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=false
pull.rebase=false
credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath=true
init.defaultbranch=master
http.proxy=http://<redacted>
http.sslbackend=schannel
https.proxy=http://<redacted>
user.name=<redacted>
user.email=<redacted>
winupdater.recentlyseenversion=2.24.1.windows.2
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
credential.http://<redacted>.provider=generic
diff.tool=vsdiffmerge
difftool.prompt=true
difftool.vsdiffmerge.cmd="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\vsdiffmerge.exe" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" //t
difftool.vsdiffmerge.keepbackup=false
merge.tool=vsdiffmerge
mergetool.prompt=true
mergetool.vsdiffmerge.cmd="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\vsdiffmerge.exe" "$REMOTE" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$MERGED" //m
mergetool.vsdiffmerge.keepbackup=false
mergetool.vsdiffmerge.trustexitcode=true
credential.https://<redacted>
gui.recentrepo=<redacted>
gui.recentrepo=<redacted>
gui.recentrepo=<redacted>
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=https://<redacted>
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.main.remote=origin
branch.main.merge=refs/heads/main
branch.Prod.remote=origin
branch.Prod.merge=refs/heads/Prod
```

As you can see the number of modified files varies wildly in the git posh status summary:

- `[Prod ≡ +0 ~974 -0 !]`
- `[Prod ≡ +0 ~336 -0 !]`
- `[Prod ≡ +0 ~223 -0 !]`
- `[Prod ≡ +0 ~90 -0 !]`
- `[Prod ≡ +0 ~959 -0 !]`

As @eftshift0 pointed out it could be an EOL problem, I thought it may be a good idea to add `.gitattributes` here:

```
# Auto detect text files and perform LF normalization
*          text=auto

*.cs       text diff=csharp
*.cshtml   text diff=html
*.csx      text diff=csharp
*.sln      text eol=crlf
*.csproj   text eol=crlf
```

Edit:

- This problem exists on multiple machines in our office. Ideally, a solution would be repo-specific.
- Added `git config -l` to output.
- Added .gitattributes
- Added section to point to git status summary

Comment: that looks like an EOL format change. Can you add the output of this to the question? `git config -l`

Comment: I've added `git config -l` to the output.

Comment: All those LF/crlf lines could be the problem.... It's likely that they are changing the files in the working tree and why you are seeing this.

Comment: Yeah, we guessed that, too and commited those changes in the past. But they keep showing up and, as shown in the log, the number of files affected varies greatly. Therefore, it looks like a bug (and/or race condition) for me.

Comment: What number of files? I see `1597` in every checkout.

Comment: I'm referring to modified files in the git posh status summary: `[Prod ≡ +0 ~974 -0 !]`, `[Prod ≡ +0 ~336 -0 !]`, `[Prod ≡ +0 ~223 -0 !]`, `[Prod ≡ +0 ~90 -0 !]`, `[Prod ≡ +0 ~959 -0 !]`

Comment: @Chake: the `~223` in git posh output refers to the number of modified tacked files ?

Comment: @Chake: another recurrent gotcha on windows is the case insensitive file system. Can you check if you have tracked files in git, where git has stored two case sensitive variants for some paths ? `git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD: | sort -f`, and look for duplicate lines in there (for example: look for `ILandDao.cs` in the output)

Comment: @LeGEC correct regarding the status summary (https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git?tab=readme-ov-file#git-status-summary-information). 
I have found no files which only differ in case sensitivity.